# How can I find the amount of floating point operations for each MHz for processor X?

Tags: cpu, performance

I've decided to buy a certain processor (laptop Intel-Core-i7-4790K 4GHz-4.4GHz turbo), but it pains me that I can't tell how many GigaFLOPS(G[FLOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS)) the processor actually has. I also can't find how many floating point operations it does in one cycle. As I understand such operations are a good indication of how good a processor is in real life use for a heavy application/game.

Is there a website that benchmarks all new cpu's (or atleast this one) with clearly the gflops or number of floating point operations per cycle outcome on it's own somewhere(without other benchmarks mingled into the numeric outcome) and preferably outcomes per core (but I can also just divide the outcome by number of cores manually, because unlike more varied benchmarks this should work).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of CPUs and their speeds [here](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/).

Comment: Those aren't "speeds" they're unclear benchmarks especially because having more cores doesn't equal more speed for a single thread(think python script or game engine logic loop)
In other words these will run faster where it often doesn't really matter(they won't speed up a single threaded python script in my case). I need gflops for a single core or the total gflops of all cores as these in contrast ARE easily divisible by the number of cores to give the real max speed of a single core for floating point operations. :)

Comment: The benchmarks are clear. It's that they don't offer exactly what you want. As far as cores are involved, Even though there may be eight cores in the CPU, I believe that there is only one FPU for all 8 cores. You will need to check with Intel and AMD to be certain.